# Split single row xml path result into multiple rows

Tags: sql, for-xml-path

I'm after a bit of guidance here. I have a table that has all the data I need all mixed together in a single column (attributes) like so:

```
Device Index     Attribute index     Attributes
      5               59              WS020121
      5               83              9C-B6-54-A0-41-40
      5               90              GROUP\darkwahm
      6               59              WS020122
      6               83              9D-B8-54-A0-50-40
      6               90              GROUP\darkperm
```

What I am trying to do is split out the data into multiple columns so it will display as:

```
   Device              Mac Address              User
   WS020121            9C-B6-54-A0-41-40        GROUP\darkwahm 
   WS020122            9D-B8-54-A0-50-40        GROUP\darkperm
```

After some research I was advised to use the XML path to get these results so I created a query which is:

```
SELECT cast (av1.attributeValue as varchar(50)) + ','
   --cast( av1.attributeValue as varchar(50)) + ','
FROM [dbo].[DeviceAttributes] Av1 
WHERE av1.AttributeIndex=59 or av1.AttributeIndex=83 or av1.AttributeIndex=90
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

This works in the sense of all my data is together but its in a single row all together like this:

```
WS022743,B0-5A-DA-B4-51-01;60-6D-C7-34-86-05,GROUP\darkwahm,WS022871,D0-27-  88-92-9B-8A,GROUP\securitypc,ABSE-PEARSOND,00-05-9A-3C-78-00;68-F7-28-92-0E-7A,GROUP\SlavinM
```

Just wondering how I need to tweak the query to get it split across multiple columns and rows like how I mentioned above.

Comment: How do you know, that `9D-B8-54-A0-50-40` Mac Address belongs to `WS020122` Device and not to `WS020121` ?

Comment: Apologies I forgot to include a device index column that identifies them. I have amended my OP now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to your query, numbers: `59, 83 and  90` are constants for these rows, if yes, you can try this:

```
SELECT t1.Attributes as device,  t2.Attributes as  Mac_Address , t3.Attributes as "user"  from 
(SELECT Device_Index, Attributes  FROM [dbo].[DeviceAttributes] WHERE Attribute_index= 59) t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Device_Index, Attributes  FROM [dbo].[DeviceAttributes] WHERE Attribute_index = 83) t2
ON t1.Device_Index = t2.Device_Index
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Device_Index, Attributes  FROM [dbo].[DeviceAttributes] WHERE Attribute_index = 90) t3
ON t1.Device_Index = t3.Device_Index
```

Comment: That looks to have done the trick. I thank you much appreciated :)

Comment: @AdamBriers  - Then please accept answer if that helped you   ;)